# Dynamic Axis in WPF Toolkit LineSeries Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using WPF Toolkit for charting. I am using a `LineSeries` for displaying the data change per second. Currently, I am able to update the graph as new points are added. But the X-Axis scale is fixed from 0 to 60 automatically. What I want is, after the first cycle, instead of the data plot showing from the starting of the axis, I want the X-Axis to shift by one division, like it is in an ECG display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer on my own. Please give suggestions fro improving the answer.

```
namespace WpfChartExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<ChartData> chartData;
        ChartData objChartData;
        Thread MyThread;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            chartData = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
            DateTime dtnow = DateTime.Now;
            objChartData = new ChartData() { Name = dtnow, Value = 0.0 };
            chartData.Add(objChartData);
            chartData.Add(new ChartData() { Name = (dtnow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)), Value = new Random().NextDouble() * 100 });
            chartData.Add(new ChartData() { Name = (dtnow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)), Value = new Random().NextDouble() * 100 });
            xAxis.Minimum = chartData[0].Name;
            simChart.DataContext = chartData;
            MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartChartDataSimulation));
        }

        public void StartChartDataSimulation()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    var data = new ChartData() { Name = DateTime.Now, Value = new Random().NextDouble() * 100 };
                    chartData.Add(data);
                    if (chartData.Count % 40 == 0 && i == 0)
                    {
                        xAxis.Minimum = chartData[i + 1].Name;
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (i >= 1)
                    {
                        xAxis.Minimum = chartData[i + 1].Name;
                        i++;
                    }
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((string)btnStartStop.Content == "Start Simulation")
            {
                if (MyThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
                {
                    MyThread.Start();
                }
                else if (MyThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Suspended)
                {
                    MyThread.Resume();
                }
                btnStartStop.Content = "Stop Simulation";
            }
            else
            {
                MyThread.Suspend();
                btnStartStop.Content = "Start Simulation";
            }
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running ||MyThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            {
                MyThread.Suspend();
            }
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

    }

    public class ChartData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        DateTime _Name;
        double _Value;

        #region properties

        public DateTime Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public double Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _Value;
            }
            set
            {
                _Value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfChartExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:chrt="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <chrt:Chart x:Name="simChart" Title="Simulation" Background="Beige">
        <chrt:LineSeries IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                         DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                         Background="DarkGray">
            <chrt:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type chrt:LineDataPoint}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chrt:LineDataPoint">
                                <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="1">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}" 
                                        ContentStringFormat="X-Value: {0:HH:mm:ss}"/>
                                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DependentValue}" 
                                        ContentStringFormat="Y-Value: {0:###.###}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                 Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </chrt:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <chrt:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
                <chrt:DateTimeAxis Name="xAxis" ShowGridLines="True" Orientation="X">
                    <chrt:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="chrt:DateTimeAxisLabel">
                            <Setter Property="StringFormat" Value="{}{0:mm:ss}" />
                        </Style>
                    </chrt:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                </chrt:DateTimeAxis>
            </chrt:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>

            <chrt:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                <chrt:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" Minimum="-50" Maximum="50"></chrt:LinearAxis>
            </chrt:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
            <chrt:LineSeries.Title>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">Time<LineBreak/>vs.<LineBreak/>Random<LineBreak/>Data</TextBlock>
                </chrt:LineSeries.Title>
            </chrt:LineSeries>
    </chrt:Chart>
    <Button Name="btnStartStop" Width="Auto" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" Click="btnStartStop_Click">Start Simulation</Button>
</Grid>
```